# what does までに mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

なお、参考までに反対に成功した場合の原因帰属を括弧の中に書いておく。

= roughly: The cause-association for the case where things conversely went well is written in the brackets.

Does the madeni mean' before the reference here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

参考までに means "just for reference".

---

According to 明鏡国語辞典, the までに is:

> まで ㊁〘副助詞〙
>   ➌㋐ 事柄を軽いものとして示す。
>   （表現）「ご参考**までに**お送りします。」などは、これを慣用的に使ったもの。「ほんの…として、」の意。

---

Example:

> ご参考**までに**ここに過去５年間の統計があります。
>   Just for reference [your information], here are statistics for the past five years.
>   (from *Progressive Japanese-English Dictionary*)